# What is the difference between primary and system partition

Tags: windows-8, windows-installation, system-reserved-partition

I was trying to update my system to windows 8, now at partition selection window it shows,
**partition 0 as system partition and my three other partitions as primary partitions**
when I select one of my primary partition which has 60GB of free space, it shows an error saying something like **insufficient space to install**, I read an article which says windows 8 only require 21 GB of free space but I got an error at 60GB though. I tried after formatting the partition but same error. Than I tried on *partition 0 (system partition)* it successfully install the windows. So my question is, *what is the difference between these two partitions and why one shows error and another doesn't?*

Comment: [What's the difference between system, dynamic, primary partition?](http://serverfault.com/q/254946)

Comment: So this system partition was or was not a primary partition?  What are the sizes of those other partitions, I bet one, wasn't large enough.

Comment: The other one (system partition) is only 30 GB @Ramhound

Comment: I didn't ask what size it was.  I asked if it was a primary partition.  I also asked the size of the other primary partitions besides the 60GB partition.

Comment: It shows only system partition here (don't know whether it's a primary partition or not). Actually it was only of some MBs initially than I extend it to 30 GB. And my other partitions are 250 GB and 170 GB.

Comment: But the question remains why it doesn't accept one of my partition @Davidpostill